# How can I pip install pyx package from externally hosted source?

Tags: python, pip, pyx

Pip knows about the pyx package:

```
$ pip search pyx
PyX - Python package for the generation of PostScript and PDF files
```

Trying to install it gives an error:

```
$ pip install pyx
Collecting pyx
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pyx
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external pyx to allow).
  No distributions at all found for pyx
```

I followed the error message and used `--allow-external pyx`, but got a different error:

```
$ pip install --allow-external pyx
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

How can I use pip to install the pyx package?

Comment: try `pip install --allow-all-external --allow-unverified elementtree elementtree`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell pip to both allow the external pyx package *and* to actually install it.

```
pip install --allow-external pyx pyx
```

Written in that order, it seems redundant, but the package name to install is separate from the `--allow-external` option.

Answer (score 0):

well,i had a same problem but i solved the problem using the given command.

the below mentioned command is for python2

sudo pip install pyx==0.12.1